# jQuery событие onclick на динамических элементах

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Сейчас работаю с таблицами, с возможностью редактирования данных с использованием ajax. Для этого при помощи jQuery при клике на кнопку меняю ее иконку (для этого изменяется id и class). После я должен кликнуть на этот элемент (сохранить) и кнопка должна вернуть первоначальный вид (снова сменить id и class).
Но проблема в том, что второй раз событие клика не срабатывает, хотя я даже элемент не удаляю, а просто меняю его атрибуты. Естественно, прогуглив что для этого есть второй вид клика, его я и использовал:

```js
/* Events after clicking on edit button */
$("button[id^='editRow']").on('click', function () {
   /* Get id of row */
   var rowId = $(this).attr('id');

   var newRowId = rowId.replace('edit', "save");

   /* Change icon and style of button */
   $(this).find('span').attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok');

   /* Set new id for saving data */
   $(this).attr('id', newRowId);
});


/* Events after clicking on save button */
$("table").on('click', "[id^='saveRow']", function () {
  $(this).find('span').attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil');
});
```

События клика срабатывает, но почему то два раза. Первый после присваивания нового id и второй после клика. Этого допускать нельзя, так как выйдет два раза сохранение в бд.

Comment: а зачем менять `id`?

Comment: @Grundy чтобы срабатывало второе событие, save,  а не edit.

Comment: Назначайте обработчики по классам и проблем не будет :)

Comment: @Grundy пока не совсем понимаю как это реализовать, чтобы различать какая кнопка нажата и какой id у строки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Grundy:

> Назначайте обработчики по классам и проблем не будет :)

```js
/* Events after clicking on edit button */
$("table").on('click', '.glyphicon-pencil', function () {
   $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-pencil');
   $(this).addClass('glyphicon-ok');
});

/* Events after clicking on save button */
$("table").on('click', '.glyphicon-ok', function () {
   $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
   $(this).addClass('glyphicon-pencil');
});
```

```css
.glyphicon-pencil
{
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.glyphicon-ok
{
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td><div class="glyphicon-pencil"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="glyphicon-ok"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: можно чуть более говорящие классы типа `save`, `edit`, но идея уловлена верно :)

Comment: @Igor Спасибо, все отлично работает, осталось только понять, почему срабатывает то с первого нажатия, то с пятого, а так работает)

Comment: @Igor Хотя уже понял, срабатывает когда на span попадаешь мышкой) Еще раз спасибо.